# How do i refresh power query data using power automate and send the update excel to email?

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, power-automate, power-automate-custom-connector

i have power query report which need to refresh every day and send the report via email.
The problem is, i try to use Run Script in power automate to refresh the data but its still not updated.
I read that power automate has limitation for this feature, but in a way if u have any suggestion or workaround for this problem, I would be so grateful. Thanks!

Workaround to refresh excel using power automate

Comment: You can't unless you use PowerAutomate Desktop.  `Run script` is for Office Scripts.  What's the data source?  Is it SQL?  If so, you have a chance but you still need to change your architecture.

Comment: Hi, my datasource is excel file. So there is no way to use the Run Script in the power automate ya?

Comment: No, not possible.  What does your PowerQuery do?  By what you're saying, you're taking an Excel file and running Power Query over it to refresh another Excel file, is that right?

Comment: if not using run script, is there any other way to refresh using power automate?

Comment: Answers my questions first because it may dictate my answer to your question.

Comment: By what you're saying, you're taking an Excel file and running Power Query over it to refresh another Excel file, is that right? 

answer: i refresh the query in the exact excel file.

Comment: No, what is the data source?!? The end result is an excel file, that’s known. But where does the data in your query come from? SQL DB? CSV file??? What?

Comment: data source is from csv file. thanks.

Comment: PowerQuery, from a cloud perspective, works in a few places, ADF, PowerAutomate via the SQL connector and PowerBi.  You have a few options, all of which requires at least two services.  You could do it using SQL and PowerAutomate but it might also require a third party connector.  You'd also need to store the file somewhere it can be accessed by PowerAutomate, for which, there are a plethora of places.  You question requires an architectural answer and is not simple.  If you want to continue the approach you're on, look at using UiPath, PowerAutomate Desktop or Selenium to run the refresh.

Answer (score 0):

I know Power Automate can refresh Power BI Datasets. Perhaps you could turn your query into a Power BI Dataset, and either refresh automatically in the service or via a flow.

Comment: Thanks! meaning that i need to make my query in power bi and  try refresh by flow.

Comment: correct. The easiest ways to transfer the queries would be to copy the M code from the advanced editor. Then in power bi, create a new blank query, open advanced editor, and paste in your query from excel.